# When are we allowed to do "column"-operations?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Lets say you have the linear system $Ax=b$, and you write the matrix

$[a_1\ a_2\ldots a_n \ b]$.

We defined 3 column-operations as follows: swapping two columns, or multiplying a column with a real number that is non-zero, or adding a multiple of one column to another.

**I am wondering in which situations these operations might be useful?** I tried looking back at my linear algebra book, but it only spoke about row-operations.

The reason I am wondering about this is what happens when we want to check the linear independence relations of the columns. That is, solving the equation $Ax=0$. Then since adding a multiple of a vector to another, swapping a vector with another, or multiplying a vector with a non-zero number doesn't change the linear indpendence relations, is it then correct to say that **if we only want to check the linear independence relations of the columns of a vector we can do both row and column operations to find the pivot positions?**

Comment: Note that column operations are row operations on the transpose. But a matrix has linearly independent columns $\iff$ it is invertible $\iff$ its transpose is invertible $\iff$ it has linearly independent rows.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks, but that would require it to have the same number of rows as columns, I don't assume that.